# Is it possible to remove gems from sockets?

Tags: dota-2

The Three Spirits patch just added the ability to create sockets in items and then add gems to those. I've heard that adding a gem where there's one already will destroy the old one. Does that imply that there's no way to remove gems? What about if you use a hammer on an item that has been socketed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can purchase at the store in game an item called (Unusual and normal) Artificier's Hammer which allow you too remove a gem socketted :

- On an item with the normal
- On an unusual courier with the Unusual.

Note that the Unusual courier will be destroyed (if you read the descritpion of the Unusual Artificer's Hammer) but the item is not destroyed (after having tested)
[See this guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=195749123)

Comment: I would kind of like some clarification on the normal Artificer's Hammer, but this seems good to me in hindsight.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot get it out without destroying, plus just put it in another item on the same hero.

Comment: Without destroying what? What about putting it on another item of the hero?

Comment: He means that you should put that new gem inside another item for that hero so you get to keep all the gems, on multiple items at once, to switch as you please.